# Default directory for zsh (cygwin) terminal is home not working directory VSCode on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, cygwin, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have setup custom profile for zsh via Cygwin in VSCode as below:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "zsh": {
        "path": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "args": ["--login", "-c", "zsh"],
        "overrideName": true,
        "color": "terminal.ansiRed"
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "zsh",
```

But the default directory is **/home/ADMIN**, not my working directory (repo directory of source code I'm working). Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Since this deals with configuration of VSC, please ask it on [su].

Comment: One more point: Why do you write in your VSC profile _bash.exe_, if you want to run _zsh_?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you say. I just start bash of Cygwin and run "zsh" command start zsh

Comment: Why do you run bash in order to execute zsh? You could execute zsh directly, in the same way as if you would configure a plain bash shell.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "CHERE_INVOKING": "1"
},
```